# Azure Application Gateway prompting for Credentials Multiple times (my app using Windows Auth)

Tags: azure, iis, virtual-machine, windows-authentication, azure-application-gateway

I am wondering if someone can help me guide in the right direction.
Since I put my App (hosted on IIS on a VM in Azure) behind the Azure Application Gateway (v2) I am being asked multiple times to put my username and password.
P.S. I am using Windows Authentication for my app. Everything works fine without the gateway.
I have seen [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60900680/multiple-login-prompts-from-azure-application-gateway-v2) but going back to V1 is not an option unfortunately.

Anyone here came across this and fixed it?
Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "asked multiple times to put my username and password"? You hosted the application in the IIS and access it outside. What is the authentication for the app?

Comment: @CharlesXu browser prompts for user credentials. I am using Windows Auth to authenticate users against AD, so browser uses builtin popup to ask for credentials. This pop up is being shown multiple times even if correct creds are being put everytime

Comment: Do you use the IE browser?

Comment: @CharlesXu nope, only Chrome so far

Comment: If the authenticate is necessary? It's for the HTTPS or other thing and what's that?

Comment: @CharlesXu authentication is absolutely vital, its for every request going to the webserver mostly https. Anyway we fixed it using v1 version of app gateway

Answer (score 1):

Instead of downgrading to V1, I found one more solution i.e. to use basic authentication instead of windows authentication.

I understand that basic authentication sends credentials as plain text but if you are using SSL on top of it, it should be okay.

Still looking for a better approach though to solve this but this worked for me. Hope it helps !